# swift 3 - play video in fullscreen when rotated to landscape

Tags: ios, video, swift3, autorotate

I have a container view that plays the video in it when device is portrait.
I want the video to play fullscreen automatically when device is rotated.
I've tried this code that detects when device is rotated but it doesn't change the container to full screen

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape) {

        videoContainerView.frame = self.view.frame
       // self.videoContainerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height) // this didn't work to....
        print("Device is landscape")
    }
    else{
        print("Device is portrait")
    }

}
```

The video is on an avplayer player.
thank's

Comment: May by `layoutConstraints` can help your problem?
Just bind your `videoView` to `containerView`

Comment: they are bounded together already...

Comment: I Found a solution by setting the AvplayerController to the screen size when rotated. now I just need to find a way to dismiss the navBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.k. so i managed to play the video fullscreen by adding the video to an AVPlayerLayer and setting it's size to the view when Device is landscape.

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape) {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.view.didAddSubview(self.controllsContainerView)
                       self.layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player!)
                        self.layer?.frame = self.view.frame
                        self.layer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.layer!)

        }
        print("Device is landscape")
    }
```

when UIDevice.cuurent.orientation.islandscape == false   i remove subLayer and set the view back to videoContainer bounds.

```
else{
        print("Device is portrait")
        movie.view.frame = videoContainerView.bounds
        controllsContainerView.frame = videoContainerView.bounds
        self.layer?.removeFromSuperlayer()


    }
```

hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I found another and better way to solve this problem because on this way the controlls are visible. the main idea is to move the AVPlayerViewController object to A new subView and set It's frame to full screen.  here is my code..

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape) {


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.playerController.player = self.player
                        self.addChildViewController(self.playerController)
                        self.view.addSubview(self.playerController.view)
                        self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        }
        print("Device is landscape")
    }
```

When device is rotated back to portrait add this subView to the previous frame and set it's size again. here's my code.

```
else{
        print("Device is portrait")
        videoContainerView.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = videoContainerView.bounds
        controllsContainerView.frame = videoContainerView.bounds
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me, as I was using an AVQueuePlayer:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape) {
            self.landScapeAVController           = AVPlayerViewController()
            self.addChild(self.landScapeAVController!)
            self.landScapeAVController!.player   = self.queuePlayer
            self.landScapeAVController!.view.tag = 999
            self.view.addSubview(self.landScapeAVController!.view)
        } else {
            let topView                          = self.view.viewWithTag(999)
            topView?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.landScapeAVController?.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```